# How to get text of Div by DivId

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my sample code:

```
<div id="divSPLMessages" class="error" style="width:480px;">
<ul>
<li>This record is already used.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How do i read the text 'This record is already used.'

Comment: Have you tried anything..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = $("div ul li").text();
alert(text);
```

This should solve it

If you are using plain javascript without any libray then

```
var text = element.firstChild.nodeValue;

//considering li is the element tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
$("div#divSPLMessages ul li").text();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/My8Jr/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = $('#divSPLMessages ul li').text();
    alert(test);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("divSPLMEssages").innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get complete content of that element use:-

```
$("div#divSPLMessages ul li").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using W3C compatible APIs: `document.getElementById("divSPLMessages").textContent`

IE proprietary: `document.getElementById("divSPLMessages").innerText`

There are other ways you can use if you use libraries such as jQuery (which others have already posted).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript use this

```
document.getElementById("divSPLMessages").getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li')[0].innerHTML
```